# pgrep returns different results if run from script than if run in terminal

Tags: shell-script, openwrt, pgrep

I have written a script to check how many instances of a process are running in an OpenWrt based system. If I run the following in my terminal

```
COUNT_PS=$(echo `ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli | wc -l`)
root@SHAULA-720:~# echo $COUNT_PS
```

the result is

```
1
```

Below is the code of the shell script , if I run this script the result is 4 instead of 1

```
#!/bin/ash

#for debug 
ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli



COUNT_PS=$(echo `ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli | wc -l`)
echo we have $COUNT_PS instances for upmpdcli;
logger we have $COUNT_PS instances for upmpdcli;

if [[ $COUNT_PS == 1 ]]; then        
    logger "we have only one instance"


 #HERE PUT CODE TO START NEW PROCESS
elif [[ $COUNT_PS == 2 ]]; then
    logger "we have 2 instances lets kill all and start a single"
    kill -9 `pgrep upmpdcli`

elif [[ $COUNT_PS == 0 ]]; then
    logger "we have no instance lets wait for cron to start it"


else
    logger "we have $COUNT_PS  instances"
fi
```

so if I run `/etc/upmpd-check.sh` the result is `we have 4 instances for upmpdcli` which is strange to me.

What am I missing here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `pgrep` instead of `ps | grep`?

Comment: even with pgrep the results are same. if I run `pgrep upmpdcli | wc -l` from terminal I would get proper result 1, but when I would run the script it will result 4

Comment: What is the output of `ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli` at the terminal and in the script? Are they showing the same set of processes, or just a snapshot of processes that rapidly get created and killed?

Comment: since you have pgrep, I want to make sure you're aware of pkill as well.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I see the output of ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli has the script as well in result . but still the count should be 2 not 4. see my edited answer

Comment: It's catching your shell script's name too. Why don't you just use `pgrep` and `pkill` with the appropriate expression and options?

Comment: Does it work as expected if you use `COUNT_PS=$(ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli | wc -l)`? No `echo` and no backticks?

Comment: You could simply run  `$(ps -w | grep -c [u]pmpdcli)` if you want to use your way of doing it. But there are more sane ways to do it

Comment: I wonder if the subshell created with the backticks in `COUNT_PS=$(echo \`ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli | wc -l\`)` is creating another instance of your shell script to appear in `ps`. Can you edit your script so that line is `COUNT_PS=$(ps -w | grep -v grep | grep upmpdcli | wc -l)` ?

Comment: I think using `COUNT_PS=$(pgrep -x upmpdcli | wc -l)` might be best.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `COUNT_PS=$(pgrep upmpdcli | wc -l)`  works fine thanks. can you add it as an answer so I can select it as an answer that solved the issue.

Comment: I will defer to @Kusalananda , who identified the problem ( having the program you were looking for be part of the name of the shell script), to write the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main confusion comes from your `ps | grep` pipeline matching the name of your script, which includes the string `upmpdcli`.

With `pgrep` you would not have the same issue as `pgrep` will look at the command names only by default and would not mistake `upmpdcli-check` for `upmpdcli`.

Ideally, you would use

```
pgrep -x /usr/bin/upmpdcli
```

to get the PIDs for that process.

To kill that process, or those processes, use

```
pkill -x /usr/bin/upmpdcli
```

That is, do *not* use the PIDs had from `pgrep` (as these may not be up to date).

To kill only the oldest `upmpdcli` process, use `pkill` with `-o`, and use `-n` to kill only the newest.  See the `pkill` manual.

---

Also note that

```
variable=$( echo `somecommand` )
```

is better written as

```
variable=$( some_command )
```

unless you are relying on the fact that the shell will do word splitting and filename expansions on the result of `some_command` (you are not).